How manage 3rd party libraries while creating angular libraries
I have been building multiple libraries in angular, say X, Y & Z.  And they will be loaded in the main app. These different libraries can have different node modules depending on the feature of the libraries, let say X uses highcart lib to show carts, whereas Y has ngx-avatar lib used for showing profile images in some components.
So how and where should these node modules be added, I mean they should be added in the package.json of each lib where they are used. Or all of them should loaded in the main app package.json.
I want to follow good practices for such an app structure. Moreover, I need something like if common modules that are used by all the libs and app can be placed in the app, and other lib-based modules are defined with that lib.

I think this really depends on architecture. Are libraries X, Y and Z use elsewhere? Is versioning of those libraries important? Two approaches I can think of: the results of each library could be an NPM package (so each lib has their own package.json) and you can then import these NPM packages in your main app. This might be a good approach if a lot of apps depend on specific versions of the libs. Another approach could be a mono-repo setup with for example NX. Then you have a central package.json but it will be easier to maintain dependencies.

Thanks for your answer. These libraries have secondary endpoints too, that can be called within the other libraries. And also change the fact that these libraries can be used elsewhere. Let's say if we consider this approach " can think of the results of each library could be an NPM package (so each lib has their own package.json) and you can import these NPM packages in your main app". So the packages defined in each library will also need to be defined in the package.json of the main app or not just in the package.json of that lib.

If you create separate libraries, then you define the dependencies per library. If you import the library in your main app, you import for example my-library@1.2.1 (or whatever version you might have). Just like other NPM dependencies you will import dependencies of your libraries automatically. So in the main app you only install direct dependencies; NPM will do the rest for you.
